# Moving text from the centre of a tile to the top (with screenshot)

Tags: css

First-timer here. I'm working on a camping site, basically in my spare time to teach myself code. I create some basic web pages then went about modifying a template to suit my needs. I've got to a good point in the past week, but I'm looking to move the text from the centre of my image to the top-centre. Just to make it readable, basically. Here's what it looks like right now:

[image: Camping]

I hope this is a simple fix for you guys. I know how to change the colour of the text, which I'll do after. Appreciate any help, and hope I've given enough info!

```css
/* Tiles */

.tiles {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  postiion: relative;
  margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

.tiles article {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33333% - 2.5em);
  margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
}

.tiles article > .image {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tiles article > .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tiles article > .image:before {
  -moz-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -ms-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.tiles article > .image:after {
  -moz-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -ms-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 0.25px%3B stroke: %23ffffff%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='100' /%3E%3Cline x1='100' y1='0' x2='0' y2='100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0.25;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tiles article > a {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: centre;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tiles article > a > :last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.tiles article > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.tiles article > a h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.tiles article > a .content {
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 0.35em;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tiles article > a .content > :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tiles article.style1 > .image:before {
  /* background-color: #f2849e; */
  background-image: url(images\one-man-tent.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style2 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #7ecaf6;*/
  background-image: url(images\two-man-tent.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style3 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #7bd0c1;*/
  background-image: url(images\group-tent.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style4 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #c75b9b;*/
  background-image: url(images\camping-gear.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style5 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #ae85ca;*/
  background-image: url(images\camping-checklist.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style6 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #8499e7;*/
  background-image: url(images\campsites.jpg);
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:before {
  background-color: #333333;
  opacity: 0.35;
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover .content {
  max-height: 15em;
  opacity: 1;
}

* + .tiles {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

body.is-loading .tiles article {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0;
}

body.is-touch .tiles article .content {
  max-height: 15em;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 1.25em);
    margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: calc(50% - 2.5em);
    margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: calc(50% - 1.25em);
    margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
  }

  .tiles article:hover > .image {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.25em 0 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="tiles">
  <article class="style1"> <span class="image"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="One Man Tent" /> </span>
    <a href="generic.html">
      <h2>One Man Tent</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit amet nisi lorem etiam dolor veroeros et feugiat.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, post your HTML, too. The CSS out of context isn't very helpful since we'll have to guees at which selectors target the text. And I'm assuming you're talking about the text that's centered over the tent images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's difficult to reproduce this without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hey guys, sure! Didn't want to spam you with a million lines of code! Yes, I'm talking about the text centred over the images.  Just finding a way to send the HTML without going over the character limit...

Comment: Here's the HTML @MichaelCoker

<section class="tiles">
        <article class="style1">
         <span class="image">
          <img src="images/one-man-tent.svg" alt="One Man Tent" />
         </span>
         <a href="generic.html">
          <h2>One Man Tent</h2>
          <div class="content">
           <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit amet nisi lorem etiam dolor veroeros et feugiat.</p>
          </div>
         </a>
        </article>

Comment: Jimmy, edit your question and add the HTML to the question instead so everyone can see it and it will be easier to read :)

Comment: Should be able to see it now @RickyDam

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the end goal, since the `a` is the `flex column` parent for the text, you have `justify-content: center` to put things in the center currently. Use `justify-content: flex-start` to move the text to the top.

```css
/* Tiles */

.tiles {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  postiion: relative;
  margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

.tiles article {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33333% - 2.5em);
  margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
}

.tiles article > .image {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tiles article > .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tiles article > .image:before {
  -moz-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -ms-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.tiles article > .image:after {
  -moz-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -ms-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 0.25px%3B stroke: %23ffffff%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='100' /%3E%3Cline x1='100' y1='0' x2='0' y2='100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0.25;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tiles article > a {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: centre;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tiles article > a > :last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.tiles article > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.tiles article > a h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.tiles article > a .content {
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 0.35em;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tiles article > a .content > :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tiles article.style1 > .image:before {
  /* background-color: #f2849e; */
  background-image: url(images\one-man-tent.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style2 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #7ecaf6;*/
  background-image: url(images\two-man-tent.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style3 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #7bd0c1;*/
  background-image: url(images\group-tent.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style4 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #c75b9b;*/
  background-image: url(images\camping-gear.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style5 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #ae85ca;*/
  background-image: url(images\camping-checklist.jpg);
}

.tiles article.style6 > .image:before {
  /*background-color: #8499e7;*/
  background-image: url(images\campsites.jpg);
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:before {
  background-color: #333333;
  opacity: 0.35;
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover .content {
  max-height: 15em;
  opacity: 1;
}

* + .tiles {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

body.is-loading .tiles article {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0;
}

body.is-touch .tiles article .content {
  max-height: 15em;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 1.25em);
    margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: calc(50% - 2.5em);
    margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: calc(50% - 1.25em);
    margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
  }

  .tiles article:hover > .image {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tiles {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .tiles article {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.25em 0 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="tiles">
  <article class="style1"> <span class="image"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg" alt="One Man Tent" /> </span>
    <a href="generic.html">
      <h2>One Man Tent</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit amet nisi lorem etiam dolor veroeros et feugiat.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
```